# Let $p$ be a prime. Determine the number of subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{p^2} \oplus \Bbb Z_{p^2}$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime.  Determine the number of subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{p^2} \oplus \Bbb Z_{p^2}$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{p^2}$.

I see that any subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{p^2}$ must have order $p^2$.  I can also see that $\{0\} \oplus \Bbb Z_{p^2}$ and $\Bbb Z_{p^2} \oplus \{0\}$ and $\langle kp \rangle \oplus \langle jp \rangle $ ($k$ and $j$ positive integers) are isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{p^2}$, but I can't think of any others.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: $\langle kp\rangle \oplus \langle jp\rangle$ is not congruent to $\mathbb Z_p$, it is not cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

Every element of order $p^2$ gives rise to one such subgroup. On the other hand $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ has exactly $\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1)$ elements of order $p^2$.

So what you want is $\frac{n}{p(p-1)}$ where  $n$ is the number of elements of order $p^2$ in $\mathbb Z_{p^2}\times \mathbb Z_{p^2}$, can you take it from here?